# ESP8266 - AT+CIUPDATE : Failed to update the module and the module is now unresponsive

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp8266

Recently I got my ESP 8266. It was running fine untill I hit the command AT+CIUPDATE for installing any OTA updates. The module is now unresponsive. It returns garbage values in the serial monitor when powered and connected to Arduino Mega.
Can any one help me out in this problem?

Comment: I currently have the same issue, it had been running for couple minutes. I will wait a little longer that check where it is connected to.

Comment: Left it run over night, no change. Time to reflash.

Comment: @nana: Even I had to reflash the firmware but couldn't get the firmware it was originally loaded with. Reflashing did made the module come back to its senses though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binaries become corrupt due to heating, to restore it to its normal state, use any flasher tool to re-flash the firmware onto it.